# Question around E(XY) = E(X)E(Y) for Independent X and Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X ~N(1,0.1)

According to E(XY) = E(X)E(Y), since each draw $x_i$ from X is independent from another:

$E(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i)$ = $E(X)^n$. Since $E(X)$ = 1, it follows that $E(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i) = 1$

However, due to geometric compounding, E(X) tends to 0 as n tends to infinite. (Since for example mulitplying by 1.5 and then 0.5 = multiplying by 0.75).

Therefore, in practice, $E(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i)$ will tend to 0 as n tends to infinite, rather than 1 which probability law would suggest.

The question is how can this be explained given E(XY) = E(X)E(Y) for independent events.

Thanks

Comment: $E[X^n] \not= (E[X])^n$ in general.  Here $E[X^2]=1.1$

Comment: You should note that $X$ is not independent of itself, $X$.

Comment: Here for each n X is an independent draw from the distribution. Therefore, it is equivalent to E[x1 * x2 * ... * xn] = E[x1] * E[x2] * ... * E[xn].

Comment: The product distribution  is quite asymmetric.  Take the simpler case where $X$ is either $.5$ or $1.5$ with equal probability and just let $n=2$.  Then the various products yield $(.25,.75,.75,2.25)$ with equal probability.  So, yes.  you expect the product to be less than $1$, but the one case in which it is $>1$ it is so much greater than $1$ that the expected value for the product is still $1$

Comment: Saying that $X^n=X_1\cdot X_2\cdot X_n$ is highly non-standard notation. Please edit the body of your question to remove this confusion.

Comment: The key insight is in @lulu answer.  Here's a more dramatic example: let each $X_i = 0$ or $2$ with equal probability.  Then the product $Y= \prod^n_{i=1} X_i = 2^n$ with probability $1/2^n$ and $0$ otherwise, with an expected value of... $E[Y] = 1$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the responses. It seems to me then that in practice, with a problem like this the sample mean will always be very far below the population mean. This seems to me to weaken the practical use of a theory built using this identity of E(XY) = E(X)E(Y), as there will always be very large differences in sample means obtained using each approach, even if Mathematically they're expectations are equivalent.